# Create a text in text editor using C

Tags: c, file

I want to create a C program where I ask the user to write a text, and then to save this text on a file.

this is the code I tried :

```
FILE* fichier = NULL;
fichier = fopen("filePath","a+");
printf("entrer le texte : ");
scanf("%s",txt);
fputs(nomFichier,txt);
```

The problem is when the user wants to create a text where are carriage returns, the compiler reads only the text before the first carriage return.

Is there any way when I create the file for the first time, to open it using a text editor and the program will be pending until the user close that text editor.

Comment: Your `txt` is undefined. Also, it would be good to include compilable code.

Comment: @hyde I just quote a part from my code, I have defined the txt variable as a table of char.

Comment: Launching text editor and waiting for it's exit is very platform-specific. Which platform/OS are you interested in?

Comment: @keltar I'm using gedit on ubuntu

Comment: @AimadMajdou then you could use system() function with parameter like "gedit /path/to/your/file". It will block (i.e. wait) until requested process finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening a text editor (which is really diffucult to do platform-independently), you can read more than one line of text input in your program:

```
char txt[1024];
FILE* fichier = NULL;
fichier = fopen("filePath","a+");
printf("enter the text (end with an empty line): ");
while(!feof(stdin)) {
    fgets(txt, 1024, stdin);
    if(strlen(txt) == 0) break;
    fputs(txt, fichier);
}
```

This way, your users are able to enter texts with cariiage returns and all lines are saved to the text file.

Comment: I don't really think forcing a "\n" is a nice idea.

Comment: This will stop on empty line, which may or may not be intended. I'll recommend fgets instead of scanf, and waiting for EOF instead of empty line (in unix, EOF could usually be entered by pressing control-d, not sure about dos/windows).

Comment: It is not specified by the OP whether this would be the only input for the program (in this case the EOF wuold be better indeed), or it shuld continue reading other inputs as well. The same holds for empty lines. I just wanted to show an example of an alternative solution.

Comment: @buc sorry, i had no intention to offend you or your approach. As i've said, if it was intended - then in indeed should stop at first empty line, we just don't know what was OP's intention. Your example was completely ok, i just added some hints how, depending on other factors, it could be changed.

Comment: @keltar thanks for the suggestions, I've modified the code snippet to incorporate `fgets`/`fputs`.